# Sorting characters in a string into alphabetical order without arrays or maps (Java)

Tags: java, string, alphabetical

I am trying to make a program which tests if two separate phrases are anagrams of each other. To do this, I want to sort each string phrase into alphabetical order and compare the results. However, **I want to do this without using any arrays or maps**. So far I have some pretty messy code/pseudocode:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AnagramComparer{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence.");

    String sentence = scan.nextLine();    

    sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();

    String empty1 = "";

    for(int i = 0; i <= sentence.length(); i++){

      //if char is between 97 & 122

      // if char i <= charAt (0 to sentence length - x)               

      if(sentence.charAt(i) <= empty1.charAt(0)){
        empty1.replace(empty1.charAt(0), sentence.charAt(i));                   
      }
      else{ 
        empty1 = (empty1 + (sentence.charAt(i)));
      }
    } 
    System.out.println(empty1);
    System.out.println(sentence);
  }
}
```

The idea here is that I would run through the string sentence character-by-character and sort it alphabetically in the string empty1. Feel free to tell me if I'm going in the wrong direction; any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "sorting". You simply want to sort the chars in the String.

Comment: "I want to do this without using any arrays or maps" any reason for that? It just complicates things.

Comment: I'm aware of how simple it would be to use sort.array or something similar,  but simplicity isn't my goal with this program. I want to gain an in-depth understanding of how sorting works and I want to practice using Booleans and loops.

Comment: But how do you think you can do a sort without an intermediate structure like arrays?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I was considering writing a series of conditionals to compare the ASCII values of each character in the string with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so `empty1.replace` *returns* the new string, it doesn't modify the existing one.

Since `String` uses a `char[]` internally, a new String means a new `char[]`, so **you're still using arrays**. You might as well use your own `char[]` for better performance and lower memory footprint.

```
char[] chars = sentence.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, arranging characters in a string into alphabetical order is a good idea, but it could be better to make a string like: `String alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` and check that the count of every character in alph in both strings are the same.

Something like:

```
String alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for (int i = 0; i < alph.length(); i++){
    if (StringUtils.countMatches(string1, alph.charAt(i) != StringUtils.countMatches(string2, alph.charAt(i)){
        // not an anagram
    }
}
```